# How to show date in another column If cell value changes?

Tags: excel, vba

My worksheet looks like this
[image: worksheet]

First code, example, cell a2 is "123" when I type somewhere in the sheet (example K2) "123" then text "123" matches to A2 and it adds "1" to the quantity column in this case C2.

Second code: I want, when in Qty Column(C2) some cell is filled with "1" then in Date Column(F), to show the date when Qty row was filled with "1". This code only works if I type manually "1" and not by searching the barcode with the first code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    FirstCode target
    SecondCode target
End Sub

Private Sub FirstCode(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim Item As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    'Don't run the macro if:
    'Target is not a single cell:
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    'or Target belongs to the A1.CurrentRegion:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1").CurrentRegion) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Avoid the endless loop:
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Looks for matches from the here first:
    Set SearchRange = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

    Item = Target.Value

    'Clears the Target:
    Target.Value = ""

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, Item) > 0 Then
        'There's a match already:
        Set rFound = Columns(1).Find(What:=Item, After:=Cells(1, 1) _
          , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
          , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        'Adds one to the Quantity:
        rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1

    Else
        'Writes the value for the Barcode-list:
        Range("A" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = Item

        'Looks for the match from sheet "Inventory" column A
        With Sheets("Inventory")
            Set rFound = .Columns(1).Find(What:=Item, After:=.Cells(1, 1) _
            , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
            , SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                'Writes the Product Name and puts 1 to the Quantity column:
                Range("B" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Range("C" & SearchRange.Rows.Count + 1).Value = 1
            End If
        End With
    End If

    'Enable the Events again:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub SecondCode(ByVal target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    With Target.Offset(0, 3)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A formula calculating will not cause the worksheet_change to fire.  You need to target the cells in which the physical changes are made.

Comment: Can you help me out please? Im new into vba, code is not made by me

Comment: Are you getting a debug error? Also, can you please separate the two codes so we can better help you with your issue

Comment: you need to change `If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub` to look at the column that is physically changed by the user that causes column c to change.

Comment: Scott can you write it for me please cause i dont know how exactly to do it, this is the code that should target cell and write the date

Comment: Private Sub SecondCode(ByVal target As Range)
  If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  With Target.Offset(0, 3)
  .Value = Now
  .NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
  End With
End Sub

Comment: Target.Value = "" should i put here for exampl column K?